When closing a bootstrap modal, button events are not dismissed
I am opening a modal dialog this way:
    let myModal = new bootstrap.Modal('#myModal', {
        keyboard: false,
        backdrop: 'static'
    });

#myModal has a button in it which I bind click event to in the modal shown event.
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', event => {
    $('#btnMyButton').on('click', function ()
    {
        console.log('Was clicked!');
    });
});

And when I close the modal, I am unbinding the event:
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', event => {
    $('#btnMyButton').off('click');
    $('#myModal').off('show.bs.modal');
    $('#myModal').off('shown.bs.modal');
    $('#myModal').off('hidden.bs.modal');
    myModal.dispose();
    console.log('hidden here!');
})

The problem is that, when I first show the modal dialog and press the button, click event is called once.
If I close the dialog and open it again. Click event is called twice, and so on.
How can I correctly unbind the click event? Why myModal.dispose() does not unbind events automatically?

Simply, don't register new handlers inside the shown method. Do it outside and use event delegation. $("#myModal").on("click", "#btnMyButton", fn)

Don't register a new handler each time the model pop-up opens. put handler code outside as well as use event delegation like below:
 myModal.on('click','#btnMyButton', function (){
        console.log('Was clicked!');
    });

